# PHP MySQL update only updating last row with loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up an update query which will update values entered into text fields on a while loop.Then for some reason only the last row data in the loop will be updated and the rest will stay the same.i know the issue .cause the the last attribute row overwrite the other in form so when update update only the last row

code

```
<?php
        include'../config/connect.php';
        $id = $_SESSION['agent'];

        $sql = "Select * from nps where agent_id = '$id'";
        $result = $cont->query($sql);

        if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ){
        ?>
        <form action="update.php" method="post">
        <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['phone']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['survey_date']; ?> </td>
            <td> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['agent_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['agent_id']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['agent_name']; ?> </td>                
            <td> <?php echo $row['nps_rating']; ?> </td>                
            <td> <?php echo $row['sats']; ?> </td>          
            <td> <?php echo $row['agent_satisfaction']; ?> </td>            
            <td> <?php echo $row['ir']; ?></td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" ><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></textarea></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        }

        };
        ?>
        </table>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" > </div>

        </form>
```

update.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
include'../config/connect.php';

$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$id = $_POST['id'];


if($_POST['submit']){
$sql = "UPDATE nps SET comment='$comment' WHERE id='$id' ";
};

if ($cont->query($sql) === true){
echo 'done';
}else{
echo 'notdone';
}

?>
```

Comment: `name`s in `form`s must be unique. You need a `form` for each element, or you need to make the `id` an array `id[]` then you will need to iterate over it. You also are open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have two input names: `id` and `comment`. Once submitted, the form will be processed from start to finish, meaning the values that are actually processed in your PHP will be the last ones.

You will want to make these unique, and since you’re ID is hidden, it is less important. My suggestion would be to dynamically create names, such as `comment_{id}` and than in your PHP with the query to update, you go through all of your `$_POST` values, replace out the `comment_` from the key, and execute a query to update the values.

You are also open to SQL injection and should take steps to prevent that.

Comment: Can you refer the code that solve the problem please

Answer (score 0):

You must have have inputs with unique names. I suggest to make a input name from row’s ID and attribute name, as for e.g. comment will be like ‘1-comment’. Then in the update script you need to iterate over the data and make the update query for each data. Cheers.